# Is this safe to deallocate memory from a pointer of a different type than when it was allocated?

Tags: c++, memory, dynamic

I have a question about deallocating memory in C++:

```
typedef struct type1
{
   int a;
   int b;
   float c;
} Type1;

typedef struct type2
{
   int a;
   int b;
} Type2;

void *p = new Type1;

delete (Type2 *)p;
```

In this case, will be the memory area pointed by `p` be deleted completely even after `p` was cast to type of different size?

Comment: @Johnsyweb `base` doesn't have a virtual destructor, so that's still undefined behavior

Comment: Why don't you introduce a common base class with a `virtual` dtor `struct base { int a; int b; virtual ~base() { } }; struct Type1: public base { float c; }; struct Type2: public base { }; base* p = new Type1; delete p;`?

Comment: @Johnsyweb: In case you want to use inheritance, it would be easier if Type1 (extended by attribute `c`) is derived from `Type2`. And just like Praetorian has already pointed out, `Type2` (base type) should have virtual destructor.

Comment: @Liho: That may well be easier, but often the examples given are greatly reduced from the real-world cases. I have now included `virtual ~base() { } `.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The behavior is undefined.  In this case, the dynamically allocated object may only be deleted via a pointer of type `Type1`.

First, by using the pointer obtained by `(Type2 *)p` in the `delete` expression, you violate the aliasing rules.  There is a limited set of types via which the object pointed-to by `p` may be used.  The rules from C++03 may be found [in an answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4807643/container-covariance-in-c/4807726#4807726).  The C++11 rules are similar (the differences are not relevant to the answer to your question).

Even if the program did not violate the strict aliasing rules, it would violate the requirements of the `delete` expression.  The specification states (C++11 §5.3.5[expr.delete]/3):

> if the static type of the object to be deleted is different from its dynamic type, the static type shall be a base class of the dynamic type of the object to be deleted and the
>   static type shall have a virtual destructor or the behavior is undefined.

In your `delete` expression, the static type of the object is `Type2`, whereas the dynamic type is `Type1`.  The types are different, but the static type is not a base class of the dynamic type.

Comment: Don't you have to dereference the type-punned pointer for it to be a violation of strict aliasing rules?

Comment: but what will happen in C? if p = (Type1 *)malloc(sizeof(Type1)); and then free((Type2 *)p)?

Comment: @ratzip `free` takes a `void *` argument, so the cast doesn't matter.

Comment: @ratzip: `free` only releases memory; `delete` needs to also call the proper destructor before releasing the memory.

Answer (score 4):

That would be a really bad idea, as you would be asking the compiler to arrange to run Type2::~Type2 on a Type1 pointer, and that destructor might reference off the end of the object.

In conventional environments, the eventual free of the memory would be alright, because `operator delete` calls `free` which does not care what type you called it at compile time. However, in a not so conventional environment, it could be a disaster.

Answer (score 0):

Although this question was perfectly answered by [James](https://stackoverflow.com/users/151292/james-mcnellis) already, I would like to point out one thing:

In proper C++ code, you'll almost never end up working with `void` pointers, which means your code would probably look like this:

```
SubType *p = new SubType;
BaseType* pB = (BaseType*)p;
delete pB;
```

in this case, even if the `BaseType` would have proper virtual constructor, there is still possible undefined behavior if the `SubType` is not derived from the `BaseType`. Common C-style cast isn't very lucky choice here.

But in case you would use `dynamic_cast`, compiler would most likely not let you do that in case that `p` doesn't point to object of polymorphic type. And even in case that `p` points to object of polymorphic type, but `BaseType` wouldn't be base type of `SubType`, `dynamic_cast` would return `NULL` and you could handle this state appropriately:

```
SubType *p = new SubType;
BaseType* safePtr = dynamic_cast<BaseType *>(p);
if (!safePtr) // p doesn't point to object of type derived from BaseType
    ...       // handle this situation
else          // p points to object of polymorphic type derived from BaseType
    delete safePtr;
```